# Entity Framework in .NET Standard Library

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-standard

**Scenario:**

I have a Web API application which targets .net framework 4.6.2. Now i need a scheduler like app so i am planning to create aws lambda function for this. In order to do that i am planning to create the new one in .net core. But my current priority does not allow to migrate entire application to .net core now.

**My plan:**

- Current start the new application in .net core and slowly migrate the existing Web API to .net core
- The data layer libraries need to be compatible with existing Web API (.net Framework) and new application (.net core)
- For compatibility, i am thinking to migrate my data layer libraries to .net standard

**Questions:**

As I am new .net core and .net standard I have the following confusions

- Can i use .net standard for data layer libraries also? Is this advisable?
- Which entity framework need to use? if EF core, is this work with my existing Web API? (current EF 6)
- Any issues in migration and work with .net framework and .net core

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can i use .net standard for data layer libraries also? Is this advisable?

Sure.

> Which entity framework need to use?

EF Core 2.0 targets .NET Standard 2.0. There are step-by-step tutorials of how to use it with .NET Core and the .NET Framework in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/).

> Any issues in migration and work with .net framework and .net core

Please refer to [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-entity-framework-core-2-0/) blog post for information about the most common issues and workarounds.

Comment: Great thanks.. will look into the details

Comment: sure..i am checking the articles. anyway this helped me to continue